# countrows and filtering on max number and correspondig string

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I have a pretty easy data model.
I am looking for a dax-function that looks just count the row with the max value in one specific column and a specific string in another column.

This order routing table has the following structure:

```
OrderNr    - Date     - Quantity - State - Process
100       01.01.2019     1000      5        Mounting
100       02.01.2019     1000      10       Package
```

Now I need to calculate the number of orders in this table that have "Exit" in column "Process" as the max "State"
Something like`:= Calculate(Countrows(OrderRouting);Filter(OrderRouting;[Process]="Exit" ....`

I am just struggling with the part of the dax-function how to look just on the max number in column "State".

Does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would put the max value of [State] in a variable (VAR) and use that in the CALCULATE function. Something like this:

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR maxState = MAX ( 'OrderRouting'[State] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'OrderRouting' ),
        'OrderRouting'[Process] = "Exit",
        'OrderRouting'[State] = maxState
    )
```